# Problem on residue classes modulo $p$, where $p$ is prime number.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Problem:** Prove that $\{\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{p-1}\}$ is a reduced complete set of residue classes modulo $p$ where $p$ is a prime number greater than $3$.

**My Attempt**: This problem/Lemma occurred to me while proving the following claims:

1) Let $p$ be a prime number greater than $3$ and let $(m,n)=1$ such that $$\frac{m}{n}=\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{i^2}.$$ Prove that $p|m.$

2) For $p>3$ prove that $$p^2|(p-1)!\left(\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\frac{1}{i}\right).$$

I tried to prove this Lemma in the following manner: In order to show that the set $S=\{\frac{1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{p-1}\}$ is the complete set of residues classes modulo $p$, we have to show that for any two elements $1/x,1/y\in S$ we must have $1/x\not \equiv 1/y\pmod p.$ I know that $x\not\equiv y\pmod p$ but I do not know how to take it from here.

**Edit:** After Daniel Fischer's comment, I have tried to continue my solution. So we know that for every $1<x<p-1$ there exists a unique $x'$ such that $xx'\equiv 1\pmod p$, where $1<x'<p-1$ and $x\not=x'.$ Why? Because $(x,p)=1$ and if $xx'\equiv xx''\pmod p$ this would imply that $x|p$ which is bizarre. Since $(x',p)=1$ we  can divide $x'$ and thus we obtain $x\equiv \frac{1}{x'}\pmod p.$ In this manner we can map all the remainders $1<x<p-1$ such that $x\to x'$. Also $1\to \frac{1}{1}$ and $p-1\to\frac{1}{p-1}$ since $(p-1)^2\equiv 1\pmod p$. Of course, this map is bijective and hence we are done.

Comment: Look at the modular inverses of $\frac{1}{k},\, 1 \leqslant k \leqslant p-1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for the hint. Please see the revised answer.

Comment: Note that the same is true works for any bijective map (here an  involution = self-inverse map).on that set, e.g. $\,x\mapsto x+k,\ $ and $\,x\mapsto ax\,$ for $\,a\,$ coprime to $\,p.\ $ They merely *permute* the elements.